# When talking about input and output impedances, what are we comparing them to?

Tags: impedance, input-impedance, high-pass-filter

Let's consider a theoretical highpass filter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6aPEX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to show that the worst-case input and output impedance is R but the whole concept of input / output impedance isn't really clicking for me.

Resistors have impedance. Capacitors have impedance. **How can an input or output node have impedance?** I think that they must be comparing the node to something but I'm not exactly sure.

Initially I was thinking that input impedance must be *the amount of impedance that would be met as the current traveled through my RC filter.* If the frequency was high, C1 would look like a short and the current would flow through R1 to ground. If the frequency was low, C1 would look like an open circuit and impedance would be infinite. Having a low input impedance is the worst-case scenario and I just showed that the lowest it could be is R1. So that seems to work.

Following that train of thought, I figured that output impedance must be *the amount of impedance that would be met as the current traveled through ..... the rest of my RC filter?* This train of thought suggests that C1 is irrelevant because the only place left for the current to go is through R1. That is the right answer but it seems like I got there incorrectly.

Is this right? If not, can you please explain it?

Comment: I would suggest that typically, input impedance is the impedance between your input node and ground. Technically, it's the impedance between your input node and a fixed voltage. This could be ground, or it could be a power rail.

Comment: Also, remember that you're not setting a current input, you're setting a voltage input. Yes, (if nothing is connected to the output) all the current going from Vin through the capacitor will travel through R1 to ground, the point is that the impedance of the capacitor will change the amount of current that flows through it, changing the voltage at Vout (which is what you're measuring)

Comment: The impedance of your circuit seen from the input is the impedance of the capacitor (depends on frequency) plus the impedance of the resistor (just R), seen from the output the two impedances are parallel so the impedance is the impedance of the capacitor parallel with the impedance of the resistor. Zc1//R1 calculated as Ztotal^(-1)=Zc1^(-1)+R1^(-1). and Zc1 can be calculated as 1/(2 * pi * f * C) where f is the frequency and C is the capacitance of C1 in farads

Comment: Look up thevenin equivalent, it will help you understand how an output/ input can have an impedance. the impedance is basically just the slope between the voltage and current, if an increase in voltage at an input or output of 1v leads to an increase in current of 0.1A then the input/output has an impedance of 10ohm

Comment: @Vinzent. You should post your detailed comment as an answer, as it satisfies the basic requirements of an answer. Parse it into paragraphs so it is in order by context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

§
The impedance of your circuit seen from the input is the impedance of the capacitor (depends on frequency) plus the impedance of the resistor (just R), seen from the output the two impedances are parallel so the impedance is the impedance of the capacitor parallel with the impedance of the resistor. Zc1//R1 calculated as Ztotal^(-1)=Zc1^(-1)+R1^(-1). and Zc1 can be calculated as 1/(2 * pi * f * C) where f is the frequency and C is the capacitance of C1 in farads

§
Look up thevenin equivalent, it will help you understand how an output/ input can have an impedance. the impedance is basically just the slope between the voltage and current, if an increase in voltage at an input or output of 1v leads to an increase in current of 0.1A then the input/output has an impedance of 10ohm

§
It is important to note that the way the impedance of a capacitor or an inductor differs from the resistance of a resistor is in that they don't dissapate energy due to the current*voltage in them, that is because there is a 90deg. phase difference between voltage and current in capacitors and inductors.

Comment: I think the thing I'm failing to understand is how the 2 impedances are in parallel when viewed from the output node. Wouldn't Vin need to be connected to ground in order for them to be in parallel?

Comment: Yes it would, and it is. The concept used to explain this is called superposition, the input is basically shorted to ground due to the input source.

Comment: @aust look up small signal analysis. For any impedance measurement or theoretical estimate, it only makes sense to talk about the impedance between two nodes. Input impedance is the impedance between your input node and reference (not sure if that's the right word) nodes. A lot of these answers mention ground as being the reference node, but every other dc bias point is also a reference node (you can imagine them all as being connected to ground).

Comment: Input impedance: 1) Leave Vout open. 2) Calculate impedance from Vin to ref. ---------------------- Output impedance: 1) Short Vin to ref. 2) Calculate impedance from Vout to ref.

Answer (score 1):

The simple view, for the DC case, is that the voltage source has some internal resistance, and your circuit has some resistance to ground. These form a resistor divider, so as soon as your sink is connected, the voltage on the input node is a fraction of the source voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKPMbR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In both cases, the source has an output impedance of \$100\Omega\$, but the input impedance of the sink determines what is measured on the voltmeter. In the same way, the measured value varies with source impedance if the sink impedance is constant.

Voltmeters ideally have a very high input impedance, which makes the measured value fairly independent from the source output impedance (as long as it is a few orders of magnitude smaller than the voltmeter's).

Now extending that to AC, we have capacitors and inductors that introduce complex-valued resistance. Your filter has close to infinite input impedance at DC, and close to R1 at "high" frequencies, with some roll-off in between. Nothing is known about the source, but unless it is very stiff (i.e. low output impedance), the voltage measured at your input node will be affected by the filter, i.e. your filter feeds back into the source.

If there are multiple sinks connected (e.g. a passive crossover network on a speaker), this means that the voltage on the filter output is different if all paths are connected than when just one is present.

If you go even higher in frequency, you'd reduce C1 to shift the cut-off frequency upwards. As C1 nears the capacitance of the cable, you end up with a frequency-dependent voltage-divider between the cable and your filter.

In addition, if cables get longer than a fraction of the wavelength, the time it takes for the signal to travel further affects impedance over frequency: for a signal with a frequency \$f\$ and a [coxial cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_factor) of length \$0.66\frac{c}{4f}\$, if the filter fully blocks the signal and presents infinite input impedance at this frequency, the signal is reflected back along the cable, and the peak of the wave arrives at the source when the source sends out the negative peak, so these cancel out, and from the source's point of view, the output is shorted to ground (i.e. the cable has a frequency dependent input impedance on the source side and output impedance on the sink side).

The latter is only relevant for frequencies above a few tens of MHz, because \$c\$ is fairly large.

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to be about the difficulties of finding the impedances of a high pass filter. Consider the possibility that many do not even mention impedance when analyzing filters.  As is the case in [this Wikepedia article about high pass filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter).

Impedance is usually used with reference to the output or input of an working circuit such as a transmitter or antenna. It is useful to talk about a working circuit's impedance as this relates to [maximum power transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem).  A worthy goal in electronic circuit design.

A high pass filter, such as the one in the question, is usually not talked about in such a way.  Instead a filter may be talked about in terms what it could do if added to a working circuit.  Such as orders of magnitude of attenuation and [cut off frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency).

Using the schematic of the High Pass Filter in the question, the impedance from Vin to ground is the sum of the impedances of the 1uF capacitor and the 100 ohm resistor. It is assumed this is what the OP calls the "input impedance".  The impedance of a capacitor is dependent on frequency and is given by this equation:

[image]

The impedance of the resister is simply its value, 100 ohms.

So the total impedance from Vin to ground is:

```
impedance = capacitor impedance + resistor impedance
impedance = (1/(2*Pi*frequency*0.000001)) + 100
```

(Note: We need to convert micro-Farads to Farads so 1uF becomes 0.000001F.)

A similar problem is discussed [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-4/series-resistor-capacitor-circuits/) in greater detail.

The impedance from Vout to ground is only the 100 ohm resistor.  The capacitor's far node is unconnected and therefore does not contribute. It is assumed this is what the OP calls the "output impedance".  The impedance of a resistor is simply its resistance.

So the impedance from Vout to ground is:

```
impedance = 100
```

Comment: I don't really get how this is relevant. OP is asking about filtering, not power transfer?

Comment: Hum, I think you are correct.  But the title is about intput and output impedance.  However, the question is about a filter.  That is almost 2 different things.

Comment: @BeB00, I have re-worded the answer to address both the title and the question.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: So, the answer is now more relevant to the question, but it doesnt actually answer it. OP is specifically asking what input impedance *means*. You've just said it's used with reference to inputs.

Comment: Thanks @BeB00 for the feed back.  I'm having a hard time with this.  You are correct, the question is about impedance.  But the question is clearly asked with respect to a high pass filter by its self. Normally, impedance is never mentioned when talking about filters.  Impedance is not even mentioned on the highly detailed [Wikipedia "high pass filter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter) page. So I took a step back and considered why the OP was having troubles.  I concluded he/she was trying to understand a high pass filters using terms not normally applied to filters.

Comment: ...after answering you (thinking it through) I changed my answer yet again.  I am hoping this makes it clear how I see that the OP's troubles are rooted in trying to relate impedance to only a filter and not a working circuit. (I find it humorous that another answers actually uses a working circuit (power source and load) in their example.)

Comment: So... the answer is again more relevant, but it still doesn't provide any actual answers. Like, the first paragraph has no actual explanatory stuff in it. The second one talks about maximum power transfer, which is unrelated to OPs question. The third paragraph talks about how you shouldn't even use these terms anyway. None of them are useful to answer OP's question. Input impedance and output impedance *are* useful terms for filters. You can make a RC filter with an extremely low input impedance, and one with an extremely high input impedance, while still having the same frequency response.

Comment: To round out the answer I've added equations and solved them for the schematic given in the OP's question.  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I've removed my downvote